# Animation end callback after adding points

Tags: highcharts

My chart is adding points to its series in certain interval using `addPoint()`. I've set its animation duration via `chart.animation.duration` - is there any way of calling my custom callback **after** animation is completed? I want to make it look more "live". I know about `events.redraw()`, however this is being fired on the beginning of the animation.

Comment: Frustrating!  You set up an animation complete callback on initial load, but I can't get it to work with `addPoint`: http://jsfiddle.net/p4aFS/

Answer (score 0):

You can also catch redraw function (api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.events.redraw) and use setTimeout() which will have the same time as animation time.